# Stiglitz 1976 on irrelevance of corporate financial policy

Tags: microeconomics, finance, corporate-finance

In this paper, Stiglitz gives a verbal argument as follows:

> Let  us  consider  verbally  what  actions  of the  individuals  are required  to  offset  various  actions  by  the  firm.  Assume  the  firm decreases  its  dividend  payout  ratio.  This means  that  it  has  more  retained  earnings, 
>   so,  if  the  two  basic  financial  accounting identities  are to  be  satisfied,  either  it  must borrow  less  (perhaps  it  even  lends)  or 
>   issue fewer new shares. To  make  up for the loss  in  dividends,  i.e.,  to  keep  the  same consumption  path,  individuals  buy  fewer new  shares  in  the  firm  or  buy  fewer  new bonds.  Assume  the  firm  simply  issued fewer  shares.  In  one  case,  the  value  of  the equity  grew because  of issuing  new  shares, in  the  other  case,  the  value  of  the  equity 
>   grew  because  of  retained  earnings.  From the  point  of  view  of  the  stockholders,  the two  are perfectly  equivalent.  This  change in  dividend  pay-out  ratio  thus  leaves  the debt-equity  ratio  unchanged. On the  other 
>   hand,  if  the  firm  decreases  the  number  of bonds  issued,  it  will  lead  to  a lower  debt-equity  ratio.

I could understand the logic up to this point. But I don't seem to get what follows:

> Then  individuals  borrow  on their  own  account.  One  can  think  of  it  as if  the  individual  takes  the  proceeds  of  the loan  to  purchase  the  increased  equity  in the  firm  (since  the  two  are  exactly  equal, this  is only  a convenient  way  of looking  at it;  since  all  funds  are fungible,  there  is  no real  connection  between  the  two).  The increased  borrowing  by  individuals  exactly  offsets  the  decreased  borrowing  by firms  so  markets  continue  to  clear.  Similarly,  if  the  firm  decides  to  issue  more three-year  bonds  and  fewer  five-year bonds,  the  individual  can  undertake  exactly  offsetting  actions  in  his  own  portfolio.

Dividend get reduced, the planned consumption is reduced at that period. The investor wants consumption, what the investor does is to borrow from from the market for the consumption. But why can this be viewed as the individual takes the proceeds of the loan to purchase the increased equity in the firm?